# TextCtrl widget crashing in linux

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using below code snippet, it is working correctly in windows operating system, but when comes to linux, it is closing with segmentation fault.

```
self.textMessage = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
self.hSizer2.Add(item=self.textMessage, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=3)
self.vSizer.Add(item=self.hSizer2, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=0)
self.textMessage.AppendText(message+" \n")
```

I am using redhat enterprise linux. Is it possible to replace TextCtrl widget with other widgets and are there any custom widgets for TextCtrl?

Also let me know if I miss anything in above code to avoid crash problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the traceback you get when it crashes?

Comment: For other widgets check out the wxPython demo.

Comment: Can you show a self contained sample application which shows the problem when one runs it.

Comment: Thank you....It is crashing with segmentation fault at AppendText, so instead of using AppendText, I used SetValue method, it resolved the crash problem

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in an actual runnable example on my Kubuntu 14.04 box with wxPython 2.8.12 and Python 2.7.6 and it worked just fine. See the following example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.hSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        message = "The bright red fox"
        self.textMessage = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, '', style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.hSizer2.Add(item=self.textMessage, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=3)
        self.vSizer.Add(item=self.hSizer2, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=0)
        self.textMessage.AppendText(message+" \n")

        self.SetSizer(self.vSizer)

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")
        panel = MyPanel(self)

        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It is crashing with segmentation fault at AppendText, so instead of using AppendText, I used SetValue method, it resolved the crash problem

Comment: My code crashed or yours? Is your message variable actually text?